# MVC Access array in controller from view in another controller

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc

**PH Controller**

```
List<PH> publicholidays = new List<PH>();
List<string> PHArray = new List<string>();

for (int row = 1; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    PH ph = new PH();
    ph.Subject = ((MExcel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text;
    ph.StartDate = ((MExcel.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text;
    ph.EndDate = ((MExcel.Range)range.Cells[row, 4]).Text;

    publicholidays.Add(ph);
    PHArray.Add(ph.StartDate);
}
ViewBag.Publicholidays = publicholidays;
PHArray.ToArray();
ViewBag.PHArray = PHArray;
```

I have a ViewBag.PHArray in my PHController. How can I access this array in a view that belongs to another controller? In my other controller I'm using datepicker and I want to use the array values as the holiday dates:

**Create View in Leave Controller**

```
    var array = ["2015-11-25", "2015-11-27", "2015-11-29"]
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                if (noWeekend[0]) {
                    return [array.indexOf(jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date)) == -1]
                } else {
                    return noWeekend;
                }
            }
        });
        $(function () { $('#startDate').datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends }); });
```

The `var array = ["2015-11-25", "2015-11-27", "2015-11-29"]` should be replaced with the array from PH Controller

Comment: Why would you put it in a specific controller if you want to use it in multiple controller? Put it in a separate service that returns `List<string> PHArray` (or make it a method in a BaseController)

Comment: @StephenMuecke the array values come from an excel file i import into the webpage.

Comment: Then make a separate service and pass the excel file to a method in the service that returns the values - then you can call it from anywhere.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how do I make a separate service :o

Comment: `public class MyService { public List<PH> FetchHolidays(your parameters) { your code to return the collection } }` then in the view `var holidays = new MyService().FetchHolidays(yourExcelFileParameter);` and `var dates = holidays.Select(h => h.StartDate);`